# Run NestJs service file from systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I could run my NestJs app successfully using a shell script named '**start.sh'**

```
#!/bin/bash

export NODE_ENV=dev

npm run start:dev
```

But I am unable to run this shell script from my service file in systemd.

code: test.service

```
[Unit]
Description=NestJS App Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure 
ExecStart=/home/linux/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin/node /opt/folder/start.sh
User=linux

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service file error says that 'ERROR: npm v9.5.1 is known not to run on Node.js v8.10.0. You'll need to upgrade'.

Also, I could run the project from my project directory using the cmd './start.sh'

Comment: What is `{which_node_result_version 16}`, can you show us your actual line? Also should not `ExecStart=/opt/folder/start.sh` be enough?  Considering that **start.sh** has execute permissions.

Comment: @Edgar , Updated

Comment: Since you are using a `bash` script , you should not use `/home/linux/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin/nod` to run this one, as as I said it should be `ExecStart=/opt/folder/start.sh` or `ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/folder/start.sh`

Comment: After using this,
ExecStart=/opt/folder/start.sh

I am getting error:
npm: command not found 

Though i do have npm installed

Comment: I think you should have to specify the working directory (where your node project is located). In the script `start.sh` add the line before running the `npm` command: cd /path/to/your/node_project. However that might not solve the issue so show the output of running: `whereis npm`

Comment: I had added the node project path to my start.sh script. But still I am getting the same error in the service status 'npm command not found'

Comment: Probably you have `npm` installed in another path which is not present in`$PATH` environment variable. Show the output of `whereis npm`

Comment: Here: /home/linux/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.2/bin/npm

Comment: In your service add the directive `User=youruser` (in `[Service] section`) since actually you're running the script as root which in this case I don't recommend you, it's better yo run it as a normal user. I'm not sure if adding that directive will solution the issue, if you had the same error then specify the full path, so if n your script `start.sh` use: `/home/linux/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.2/bin/npm run start:dev`